# Why does my label not move until after I drag it when I call it to after my mouse wheel event?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, awt, mousemotionevent

```
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent arg0)
{
    if(dragging)
    {
        drag.rotate();
        drag.setLocation(getMousePosition());
        getContentPane().repaint();

    }


}
```

*drag* is the label I'm dragging and it doesn't set the location to the mouse position until after I drag it again.

Comment: Posting a runnable example will rove the guess work from the answers...

Comment: Try using the `getPoint()` method of the MouseWheelEvent instead of `getMousePosition()`.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work.